# How cellular networks gets internet?

Tags: wireless, internet, access-point, network-access, mobile

Mobiles get internet but how?
From the towers, we used to get signals and communicate with others like calling or a message but coming to the internet how in the terms of networking terms like radio waves etc?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is really too broad to answer here. There are entire books on this subject, and there are multiple technologies that are "cellular networks."

Answer (score 2):

If you think in the physical layer of the networking, everything, in the end, interpreted as  1s and 0s. So according to what kind of packet you are sending to the base station, it is treated as it should be. If you're asking how it goes to the internet in the architectural point of view, the following pic might be useful for you.

The figure is from Wireless Communication Networks and Systems 1 st edition, Global edition 2016 Pearson Education, Ltd. Chapter 14 Cory Beard, William Stallings:

[image]

Hope this answer is addressing your question!